# SQL Server SELECT first

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to create a JOIN with 2 tables and having ce first element of the joined table.

My tables look like this :

**Product**

```
id
name
```

**Sales**

```
idProduct
prices
date
```

I want to have the last sales price for each product but the function `FIRST` doesn't exist in SQL Server.

Someone have an idea ?

Thanks,

Comment: This may not apply to your SQL version, but for SQL 2012 there's [the FIRST_VALUE function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh213018.aspx) that seems to do just what you want. Thought this might be helpful for someone.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can  use a ranking function like `ROW_NUMBER`:

```
WITH CTE AS(
    SELECT id, name, idProduct, prices, date,
       RN = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY idProduct ORDER BY date DESC)
    FROM dbo.Product p INNER JOIN dbo.Sales s on p.id = s.idProduct 
)
SELECT * FROM CTE WHERE RN = 1
```

[Ranking Functions (Transact-SQL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189798%28v=sql.110%29.aspx)

The `CTE` is a [common-table-expression](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175972.aspx) similar to a sub-query but more readable and maintainable.

Comment: It's still going to be sooooo slow on huge tables

Comment: @makciook: What is slow on huge tables(what is _huge_)? CTE's are slow on "huge" tables if you self-join them, you should avoid that if possible. However, the query above should not be slow with proper indices.

Comment: Thank's
I used a view for CTE and it work's

Answer (score -2):

If it's SQL Server, simply use:

```
SELECT TOP 1 * 
FROM Product p 
JOIN Sales s ON p.id = s.idProduct
ORDER BY s.Date DESC
```

Comment: That's **not** going to show the first (most recent) sale for each product - it will only show a single row - the most recent sale overall.

Comment: You must run the code before posting for others